# How I can change the quantity in the product table with Prestashop Webservice?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

When I collect data through prestashop/api/products/(id) it's always 0 even if I change the quantity database directly.
**It is possible that the data of quantity is collected in another data base table?**

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the stock method you choose, but products quantity is in tables `ps_stock_available`, `ps_stock`.

You should never change the quantity in database directly.

Comment: My intention is to change the quantity through the Webservice. That can be done?